# Opening ComboBox in Panel, Windows Narrator announces document title

Tags: accessibility, microsoft-edge, narrator, aria-role

I'm having an issue with Windows Narrator on Edge where if I have a combo box (dropdown) inside a panel (modal), opening combo box starts announcing title of the tab. This issue is specific to Edge and Narrator. NVDA on Edge or Narrator on Chrome doesn't seem to recreate the issue.

My guess was to check if `role` attribute is causing the issue, and I'm assuming here that it does. When I set panel's role attribute to anything other than `dialog` or `alertdialog`, the issue seems to be fixed, although other browsers break where they do not start reading panel after opening it.

I'm sure this is not the solution.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/lalit-umbarkar-msft/pen/rNWoYze

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on Edge Chromium. It looks like the issue is more related with Narrator. If you don't change the code then I think there's nothing much we can do. I suggest that you can provide feedback about the issue to Narrator: When Narrator is turned on, press **Narrator + Alt + F** to open the Feedback Hub to provide feedback.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I wasnt sure if this would be my code issue or Edge issue or Narrator issue.

Comment: I think it should be a product to adapt to the browser. Using NVDA on Edge with the same code has no issue, so I think it might be Narrator's issue.